# Is 18 Space Control Squadron (18 SPCS) which "detects, tracks, and identifies all artificial objects in Earth orbit" a part of Space Force?

Tags: military, united-states, space-track, space-force

According to their [twitter account](https://twitter.com/18SPCS):

> 18 Space Control Squadron (18 SPCS) detects, tracks, and identifies all artificial objects in Earth orbit.

Is 18 SPCS a US military squadron? Is it a part of one particular branch of the US military? If so, does that branch happen to be [Space Force](https://youtu.be/_AUXpnB065o)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and Yes!

The 18th SPCS (f.n.a "JSpOC") is a Part of the former "Air Force Space Command" ([Wikipedia 18 Space Control Squadron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/18th_Space_Control_Squadron)).

The AFSpC on the other hand became the "US Space Force" ([AFSpC Website](https://www.afspc.af.mil/))

Because the establishment of the US Space Force just happend only some months ago, plenty of sources and Wikipedia-Sites are outdated saying 18th SPCS is part of the US Airforce. But it is still belonging to the Department of the Air Force ([Wikipedia Dep. of AF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Department_of_the_Air_Force))